# NullReferenceException on code that shouldn't be running

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I'm writing a space invaders style game in Visual Basic for my HSC Software Design project. As part of that, I am using the following line of code to detect whether an enemy hit the player's ship.

```
If ship.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemy(i).Bounds) And enemy(i).Visible = True And ship.Visible = True Then
```

This code is located within a For loop that runs for each enemy. I use that loop to move the enemies as well as check shots and stuff. This For loop runs within a Timer set to a 1 millisecond delay.

I am receiving a NullReferenceException error on this line, and it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I know that means one of either enemy(i) or ship isn't set to an object instance or something, because I've already closed the form. Here's the interesting bit:

Firstly, I received this error when this form wasn't even loaded. During the time the application was running, this form was never opened.

Secondly, even if it was running, it occurred quite a while after I stopped the timer with Timer2.Stop(). I checked through my code and there is no way possible that this code should try to execute.

I'm so confused right now, what is going on?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that row, and look at the stack trace to see where it's called from.

Comment: I'm using VB Express 2010, how can I look at the stack trace?

Comment: I'm betting the form *is* being loaded, and you need to widen your view to how that's happening instead of being focussed on that form. Also as a side note, you should look at using 'AndAlso' instead of 'And'.

Comment: Are you getting exceptions when stepping then code or when normally running?